# Easiest Way to Run Parallel Processes in a Unit Test With Assertion

Tags: python, unit-testing, parallel-processing

I have a unit test that I want to write, that's meant to check that a second instance of my class running at the same time can't acquire a locked file.

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self):
        # get file lock
```

What I want to be able to do is have two instances of `Foo.bar()` running at the same time, *and* be able to assert that an error gets raised.

At the moment I'm using (trying to use) threading, but it's not raising the exception. If I try to run two instances from command lines at the same time, the error that I expect does get raise though.

```
import threading
from nose.tools import assert_raises

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=Foo().bar)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=Foo().bar)
thread1.start()
with assert_raises(RuntimeError):
    thread2.start()
```

Is there a way to get the behaviour that I want?